# How to get the id values dynamically to the ajax call variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

In the below coding I will get id dynamically (id="drop").

I need this id value to another Auto search function.

Based upon the id have to search categories from the database..

```
     <div class="search_dropdown">
            <select name="category" id="drop">
                <option value="">categories</option>
                <?php
                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                $sql = "SELECT title, category_id FROM directory_categories";
                $result = $writeConnection->fetchAll($sql);
                $i = 1;

                if (count($result) > 0) {
                    foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
                        $last = "";
                        if ($i % 4 == 0) {
                            $last = "last";
                        }
                        ?>

                        <option
                            value="<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></option>

                        <?php $i++;
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

IN my script codings is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#drop').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var array = [];
                $('select :selected').each(function (i, value) {
                    array[i] = $(this).val();
                });
                //here make your ajax call to a php file
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl();?>listings/search/autosearch",
                    data: {selected_values: array, otherVal: 'something else'}
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

In my function codings is....I did't get any output..It showing result as Null

```
public function autosearchAction()
{
    $array = $_GET['selected_values'];
    vardump($array);die();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        //do something with the key/value.
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script coding, instead of

```
$('drop').click(function (e) {
```

Use

```
$('#drop').click(function (e) {
```

Because `drop` is id of select element and in jQuery if we use id as selector then we must precede it with `#`

And you should use `success` method of ajax to get ajax response as follows

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl();?>listings/search/autosearch",
    data: {selected_value: $('#drop').val(), otherVal: 'something else'}
            },
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: In your ajax PHP file, you wrote `die()`. Try after removing it

Comment: And what is `$_GET['q'];` ? I think this parameter is not passing from your javascript ajax call

Comment: Not getting any value $array autocomplete action

$array = $_GET['selected_values'];
vardump($array);die();

Comment: I think you don't need to pass array for selected values because you have not multiselect mode for select control. So you can use `$( "#drop" ).val()` to pass selected option value.

Comment: You should use success method of ajax. Please check answer. I have updated it.

Comment: Now also getting the same error..It shows result NULL

Comment: Have you updated `$array = $_GET['selected_values'];` to `$array = $_GET['selected_value'];` ?

Answer (score 0):

`$('drop').click(function(){ ... })` has no mistakes in regards to syntax, but it will never get executed because it assumes that there is a native HTML `'drop'` control, the same way there is a native `'body', 'table', 'div'`, or `'select'`, etc... But there is not `'drop'` in the DOM.. `'drop'` is the id you have assigned to a `'select'` control.

So if you want your code to work, you have to tell jQuery to listen for a click on the `'select'` control, or for a control with an id of `'#drop'` and you make that clear by adding the `'#'` before the ID, indicating that it is not a native element, but and ID of an element.

```
$('#drop').click(function(){ ... })
```